# How to unpack a Python queued job results?

Tags: python, django, redis

I finally got to setting up RQ to help me with long running function calls in django, but I'm running into a problem with unpacking the values from a queue's result. I checked out the docs as per https://python-rq.org/docs/results/ but to no avail. Here's what my code currently looks like under `views.py`:

```
def render_data(request):
    reddit_url = request.POST.get('reddit_url')
    sort = request.POST.get('sort')
    res = q.enqueue(run_data, reddit_url, sort)
    val1, val2 = res.result
    data = {
        'val1': val1,
        'val2': val2,
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

The expected response would be the returned values, but instead, in console I receive an error 500 along with `createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500`. In Heroku console, the error is

```
File "/app/pc_algo/views.py", line 49, in render_data
'val1': val1,
NameError: name 'val1' is not defined
```

Am I unpacking the jobs results wrong? I've tried looking up the error but I couldn't find a better tutorial on RQ results than the one above.

Comment: Since `users_data` doesn't show up in your code example, it's clear that the code is not all there or it's wrong. Also if you enqueue a job for delayed execution, you can't expect the `.result` to be available immediately.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to change that to `val1`. As for .result, how do I set it up to wait for the value to return to continue with the rest of the function? The root of my problem is the unfamiliarity with unpacking a result, and how to pause a function until a workers done. Thanks.